# Which grant type of OAuth are connection string of in some storages?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, access-token

According to [this blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/12/22/the-complete-guide-to-protecting-your-apis-with-oauth2/), whenever a user is involved, the best grant to use is the Authorization Code grant.

A scenario is, user login to a server to query some data from a storage. After user authenticated, server code will require access token (usually a JWT with claims) with a scope of the storage. Many storages use [connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/connection-strings/) to do authorization. Server will put the access token into connection string to request for storage content.

My question is, is this process using the Authorization code grant? If not, which grant type is this.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is an authorization framework, for protecting data exposed by APIs, while meeting an organization's business rules. The API can run any possible logic to enforce these rules.

A common authorization business rule is to filter access based on the `user ID` in the access token. When users are involved, a code flow is run, to get an access token with that user ID.

Storage systems are typically not exposed to users directly, since by default they would allow a user to also get data for all other users. In some use cases at least, this would be unacceptable.

Therefore, a solution is typically designed where the API provides restricted access to the storage system. The connection from the API to the database uses a separate machine to machine security model, where authorization options are less flexible than those available to APIs.